# Fetching current x-position when graph is set to scroll in iOS-Charts

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am using `setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6)` to set maximum x-value display, so that I display only 6 chart item at a time. When I scroll to the graph to and fro, is it possible to get the highest and least scrolled x-position?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are asking, but it seems like
`lowestVisibleXIndex`, `highestVisibleXIndex` can help you. Take a look at these two properties.

Comment: I want to display only 6 bar at a time, using barChart.moveViewToX(self.currentIndex), for self.currentIndex = 0 and self.currentIndex = 20, the graph is displayed properly, when when my self.currentIndex = 12 and other values the bar is displayed half from previous and next bar. How can this be addressed?

Comment: lowestVisibleXIndex & highestVisibleXIndex are also fine but still the graph don't start at proper origin, as shown above.

Comment: it seems a bug if it is just half bar; try setup a demo project using ChartsDemo to reproduce, and file a bug on github. You could also try fix it: it seems it forget to add an offset to the left

Comment: but the same works fine if I give odd number to self.currentIndex = 7, the bars will be placed properly. only for even number I am getting this issue.

Comment: that's why it smells like a bug :(

Comment: Hi.. I need some clarification regarding "ChartMarker", as ChartMarker is subclass of NSObject, if I want to add custom view on selection of bar, instead of drawing is there any other approach?

Comment: @Ash you can take a look at ballon marker in ChartDemo how it draws a shape. it also has a image property to use. you can render your view to an image to feed marker view. or you write your own. it's flexible and up to u

Comment: I saw those things.. but i have to show lot of information like buttons, textview (which can scroll), and I have some actions to perform. Text and all I can draw but other button and all? I have to display around 10-12 views.

Comment: if you need interaction, you need to write your own views. it's beyond chart itself. so use the highlight delegate to add your views

Comment: Hi.. I need one more clarification. I want to change 'drawCircles()' in 'LineChartRenderer', so I need to subclass 'LineChartRenderer'.. but I am not getting how to map my custom Renderer with 'LineChartView'.

Comment: override LineChartView's initialize() and replace the renderer there.

Comment: initialize() is 'internal override func initialize()' i tried, but unable to override that

Comment: you need to subclass the chart view and then override it

Comment: yes.. but the method has 'internal' it can't be used outside the Charts library.

Comment: your sub class of chart view is outside of the chart library? Seems you are not using the source files, but cocoapods? If this way, you have to change the source code and compile a library yourself. In the meantime, you could raise an issue or file a PR for it.